# VBA comparison of two excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare two excel sheets using vba macro based on specific columns (will vary file to file). If the content of the columns is same then I am trying to copy the remaining column content of the destination file to source file. I have written a code for the same but I am not able to understand why its not going inside the last IF statement after calculating the value of count.

```
Sub Compare_sheet()

Dim vnt As Variant
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim myString As String
Dim F1_Workbook As Workbook
Dim F2_Workbook As Workbook
Dim k As Variant
Dim identifier() As Integer
Dim identifier2() As Integer
Dim Other() As Integer
Dim Other2() As Integer
Dim copy_cell As Variant
Dim C() As Variant
Dim D() As Variant

Count = 0

MsgBox " Please select the source file "
vnt_Source = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xls; 
*.xlsm),*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm", 1, "Please select the file to open")

MsgBox " Please select the destination file"
vnt_destination = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx; *.xls; 
*.xlsm),*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm", 1, "Please select the file to open")

Set F1_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(vnt_Source)
Set F2_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(vnt_destination)

lastRow1 = F1_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow2 = F2_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

input1 = InputBox("Input the number of identifiers you want")
ReDim identifier(1 To input1) As Integer
ReDim identifier2(1 To input1) As Integer
ReDim C(1 To input1) As Variant
ReDim D(1 To input1) As Variant

For k = 1 To input1
    identifier(k) = InputBox("Enter the identifier column number in source file")
    identifier2(k) = InputBox("Enter the same identifier column number in destination file")
Next k
y = input1

For i = 1 To lastRow1
    For j = 1 To lastrow2
        For x = 1 To input1
            C(x) = F1_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, identifier(x)).Value
            D(x) = F2_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, identifier2(x)).Value
            MsgBox "c d" & C(x) & D(x)
        Next x

        For b = 1 To y
            If C(b) = D(b) Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        Next b

        MsgBox "count" & Count

        If Count = input1 Then
            copycell = InputBox("enter the number of cells you want to copy")
            ReDim Other(1 To copy_cell) As Integer
            ReDim Other2(1 To copy_cell) As Integer

            For copynum = 1 To copy_cell
                Other(copynum) = InputBox("enter the column number of the cell to be copied in the source file")
                Other2(copynum) = InputBox("enter the column number of the same cell to be copied in the destination file")
            Next copynum

            For a = 1 To copy_cell
                myValue = F1_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, Other(a)).Value
                F2_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, Other2(a)).Value = myValue
            Next a

        End If

    Next j

Next i

MsgBox "DONE!!!"

End Sub
```

Comment: I will ask the obvious question: *does* `Count` equal `input1`? If not, then no surprise there.

Comment: After the first tym completion the count equals input1 but its getting out of the loop. I am not able to understand whr actually i am doing the mistake

Comment: I think you really need to check the values of all your variables as you loop through the code. Use a few `debug.print` statements or step through it and check the value of *all* variables (for example, if `f C(b) = D(b)` is never true, then `count` will never go up in value. [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/how-to-most-effectively-debug-code) may also prove useful reading

Comment: Thanx for answering but i have done that. I got the culprit in  the code my input1 was variant and count was Integer so it was not comparing when i changed it worked. Since i am a newbie to this VBA thing if you could let me know the exact reason. As per my understanding it may be because of the mismatch. Let me know if i require any corrections. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You never reset `Count` to zero inside the loop, so the value just keeps incrementing

```
'...
Count = 0
For b = 1 To y
'...
```

Comment: Thanx for answering the questionEven after doing so its not checking the if statement even when count = input1